# Line of SSRS footer not displaying in excel preview when exported to excel(Other elements are displaying)

Tags: reporting-services

I want to display a  horizontal line in ssrs footer .It is displayed when exporting to PDF but when it is exported to excel it is not visible(in preview pane).Other elements are visible but not the line.Any ideas?

Comment: not all elements are supported by all renderers. It might be that lines are not supported in the excel renderer. You could try a rectangle with only a top border set.

Comment: hello @Alan thank you for replying.I tried as you said by adding rectange with top border.It's not displayed as well